# Label arrays not working c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to use label arrays but it is not working i don't know what i am missing.
Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    Label[] label1 = new Label[10];  
    label1[x] = new Label();
    label1[x].AutoSize = true;
    label1[x].Text = "text";
    label1[x].Left +=10;
    label1[x].Top +=10;
}
```

Comment: In addition to Gilad Green's point, if you actually want these labels to appear in the UI somewhere, they have to be added to some control's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Also, you have an off by 1 error here in your loop. You have nothing in label[0] then label[10] doesn't exist. It appears Gilad's answer has addressed this.

Comment: @Tészta Sajtos - This time it was possible to understand the problem from the code but for next time please when you say "not working" specify what is going wrong: exception, unexpected behavior/output....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are initializing a new `Label1` array in each iteration so you will eventually have only the last one with 1 item at the last place.

Move the declaration of the `label1` outside of the loop:

```
//Move this line outside of the loop's scope
Label[] label1 = new Label[10];

//Loop from 0 to the Length of the array instead of repeating 10 again
for (int x = 0; x < label1.Lenth; x++)
{   
    label1[x] = new Label();
    label1[x].AutoSize = true;
    label1[x].Text = "text";
    label1[x].Left +=10;
    label1[x].Top +=10;
}
```

I'd recommend that you look in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) about using arrays:

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid such errors (wrong filling out), try generating arrays:

```
int n = 10;

Label[] label1 = Enumerable
  .Range(0, n)
  .Select(x => new Label() {
     AutoSize = true,
     Text = "text",
     Left = x * 10,
     Top = x * 10, 
   })
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: I do like linq and it is a great tool but I think that for this case for this level this solution is an overkill.. It is quite basic array handling knowledge

Comment: Seems like a fine enough answer, but it certainly is a bit much for a presumed beginner.

Comment: This kind of solution (generating) allows to forget about *array creation*, *index range*; e.g. code in the question uses `10` as a *magic number*  in `(for.. x <= 10...)` and in array creation `new Label[10];` wrong indexing (1-based instead of zero based) etc.